# Docker 'awslogs' fill up EC2 Volume

Tags: docker, logging, amazon-cloudwatch

I have the logging in my `docker-compose.yaml` file set up this way:

```
    logging:
      driver: awslogs
      options:
        awslogs-create-group: 'true'
        awslogs-group: <log_group_name>
```

I also have the EC2 instance successfully assuming an IAM role with permission to cloudwatch. I can see the logs. However, my volume on the Ec2 instance still gets filled up with logs! When running `df -hT /dev/xvda1` I see that 100% of the volume is used. Before I set up the `awslogs` driver I was configuring logging this way and never had a problem.

```
    logging:
      driver: 'json-file'
      options:
        max-size: '10k'
        max-file: '2'
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the awslogs driver still does not support the max-size option.

You can see the supported options for the driver [here](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/logging/awslogs/)

Seems this is a bug with the `awslogs` driver, the answer(s) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50779802/10030784) should help you get setup where all logs are being rotated correctly

Comment: Still working on answer, accidently hit the summit button while typing on mobile.. 